# How Keychain2Go get other app's keychain data on iphone?

Tags: ios, keychain

How this app [Keychain2Go](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/keychain2go/id470565680?l=en&mt=8) get all the keychain on iPhone and delete them?

As what is said in Apple's document:

> In iOS, an application always has access to its own keychain items and
>   does not have access to any other application’s items. The system
>   generates its own password for the keychain, and stores the key on the
>   device in such a way that it is not accessible to any application.
>   When a user backs up iPhone data, the keychain data is backed up but
>   the secrets in the keychain remain encrypted in the backup. The
>   keychain password is not included in the backup. Therefore, passwords
>   and other secrets stored in the keychain on the iPhone cannot be used
>   by someone who gains access to an iPhone backup. For this reason, it
>   is important to use the keychain on iPhone to store passwords and
>   other data (such as cookies) that can be used to log into secure web
>   sites.

But Keychain2Go really can. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from the documentation of Keychain2Go it provides all the secure information of your Mac in iOS device. So it does not have any ability to change the iOS keychain items.

> On iOS
>   For the first time ever, you can now access your Macs keychain on your iOS Device. You get full access to your keys stored in Keychain2Go. Never again you fail to login to your web mail account when abroad and you forgot your password on the Mac at home.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the app's feature, and thanks a ton for help!